# How to test the auto fill listbox in WPFObject("SearchBox")?

Tags: testcomplete

I have a WPFObject("SearchBox") in my WPF application.Its an autofill searchbox.On typing a text in it,it displays a listbox with text related to the search.

What is the best way to test it ?I am using TC9 and jscript.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the **Keys** method. For example:

```
parentObj.WPFObject("SearchBox").Keys("test");
```

By default, TestComplete records text typing with the **SetText** method as it works faster than **Keys**, but in some cases you need to simulate working with a keyboard and the **Keys** method is the best way to go. You can find information on this in the [Simulating Keystrokes](http://support.smartbear.com/viewarticle/56654/) help topic. Also, please see the [Entering Text into an Edit Control](http://support.smartbear.com/viewarticle/61977/) topic for information on the difference between these two methods and the [Recording Options Dialog](http://support.smartbear.com/viewarticle/55052/) topic to get information on how to make TestComplete use the **Keys** method when recording a new test.